# Why are the arguments of reduce in the order they are?

Tags: ruby

I always forget the arguments of `reduce` in ruby (https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) which is called like this:

```
(5..10).reduce { |sum, n| sum + n }
```

Is there a language design reason why the accumulator is passed in first or is it just an arbitrary choice? JS works the same way.

Comment: Related, if not a dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783001/why-would-each-with-object-and-inject-switch-the-order-of-block-parameters

Comment: That's interesting. I'd ask to leave this open though in case there's a reason that isn't just historically how it was done. I have a hunch there's something related to functional programming (currying, partial application) that's somehow related but I don't know.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a little bit more what is confusing you? You are calling `reduce` on the sequence 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, and the first iteration of the block is `5 + 6`. It seems perfectly logical to me, especially since the semantics of `reduce` is essentially "insert the operation in between all elements", i.e. `5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10` in your example.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm not confused, I was looking for a reason why the arguments were put in the order they are in the design of the function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly so you can do things like this:

```
(5..10).reduce(&:+)
```

Where that expands to:

```
(5..10).reduce { |a,b| a.send(:+, b) }
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
(5..10).reduce { |a,b| a + b }
```

So it makes sense that way. Note the order is the opposite of `each_with_object`.

Comment: I could be wrong, but don't think `Symbol#to_proc` (and thereby `&:sym`) was introduced until Ruby 1.8.7, which is long after `inject`'s argument order was chosen.

Comment: @JordanRunning That's an interesting point, but this was likely the intent.